# Factorial using recursion method in IntelliJ

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to solve a basic exercise (calculating factorial) but I am getting stuck at an error.

I am working in IntelliJ

Code:

```
public class calculation {

    public long factorial(long number) {
        if (number <= 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return number * factorial(number - 1);

    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int counter = 0; counter <= 21; counter++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%d! = %d", counter, factorial(counter));
        }
    }
}
```

Error I receive:

> Error:(18, 30) java: class, interface, or enum expected - 4 instances

I also tried reading a number from the keyboard using scanner and then calling the function but I got the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put your main method inside your class.

Comment: Remove the second `}` after the else statement.

Comment: Using a loop to call a recursive method like this only makes sense as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 extra closing bracket and because of that your void main() is out of the class. Fix that and try to run the code again. Below code is running fine.

`
public class calculation {

```
public static long factorial(long number) {
    if (number <= 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return number * factorial(number - 1);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int counter = 0; counter <= 21; counter++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%d! = %d", counter, factorial(counter));
    }
}
```

}